# Irregular shaped Windows Form (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is the easiest way to do this? Is it possible with managed code?

Comment: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3723

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
this.BackgroundImage = //Image
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.Width = this.BackgroundImage.Width;
this.Height = this.BackgroundImage.Height;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0); //Contrast Color
```

This allows you to create a form based on an image, and use transparency index to make it seem as though the form is not rectangular.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if the Opacity of the form is set to anything other than 100% (apparently .NET applies the opacity effect and then the transparancy mask).

Comment: Well, it does work, but you have to figure out what the transparency color will be after the opacity effect.

Comment: Simplest way to implement irregular forms in .NET  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/149249/Simplest-way-to-implement-irregular-forms-in-NET

Answer (score 8):

@Geoff shows the right way in winforms.

But If you are planning to use WPF instead of Winforms then WPF(.NET3.0+) gives very flexible ways to create anyshape custom windows. Check out this article also http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfpopup.aspx