# How can I make a windows application that doesn't have a square form shape?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make an application that is similar to the World of warcraft launcher.

My main concern is to not have a square windows form with the typical close buttons, but a custom shape. How can I achieve this with C# and the .NET framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Irregular shaped Windows Form (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176720/irregular-shaped-windows-form-c)

Comment: Please....please don't, [it's a bad idea most of the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/245855#245855)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on [Creating Irregular Non-Rectangle Windows using WPF](http://techpunch.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/wpf-create-irregular-non-rectangular-borderless-windows/).

Consider this tutorial for [creating Shaped Windows in WPF](http://devintelligence.com/2007/10/shaped-windows-in-wpf/). It's got sample code in C#.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great piece of source code at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/CsTranspTutorial3.aspx that allows you to make a form based off of any image with an alpha channel (like a .png), so that the transparent parts of the image correspond to places where you see through the form.