# How to drop shadow on a custom shaped Form in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency, shadow

I'm creating a custom shaped Windows `Form` (`public class Window : Form`) and need to place an appropriate shadow. The form is rectangular with round corners and I'm defining an appropriate `GraphicsPath` to get the shape of the form.

Here are parts of the code that are supposed to do this:

```
private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;

public Window()
{
 FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
 SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
 TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0, 0, 0);
}

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
 get
 {
  CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
  cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
  return cp;
 }
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
 e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

 Pen ps = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0, 0, 0));
 e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ps.Brush, this.ClientRectangle);

 Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA));
 Pen p2 = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD));
 GraphicsPath border =
     RoundedRectangle.Create(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1), 7);
 e.Graphics.SetClip(border); // I'd prefer if this came after the following two
                             // lines, but doing that results in another problem
 e.Graphics.FillPath(p1.Brush, border);
 e.Graphics.DrawPath(p2, border);
 base.OnPaint(e);
 e.Graphics.ResetClip();
}
```

The `RoundedRectangle` class is from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path).

The resulting shadow is cast as if the form is perfectly rectangular, which is best seen in the lower-right corner. How do I make the shadow draw correctly?

**Edit:** I can't believe I'm finding discussions about this on the web from 2004 (8 years ago) and still there is no solution to be found.

Comment: Possible duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176720/irregular-shaped-windows-form-c)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm asking about shadows on irregular shaped forms, the other question is just about creating irregular shaped forms.

Comment: But for irregular shape the only option for shadow is make it part of shape. Eg. use picure with shadow opacity as irregular shape. Windows drop shadow is only for native windows. Rectangular ones.

Comment: Forms seem to have trouble with semi-transparency, so any shadows will necessarily be solid and ugly. Unless there is a solution to this that I'm not aware of, which is why I'm here.